# How to round one value in a hash?

Tags: ruby

In the context of weightlifting, I'm trying to calculate the number of plates needed on each side of the bar, given the total weight to be lifted and assuming a 45lb bar. The smallest plate is 2.5lb and I'd like to round to the nearest number of 2.5lb plates required per side. Currently, given 140lb total weight, the result looks like this:

```
{:"45"=>1, :"2.5"=>0.8}
```

How can I round to the nearest whole number (0 or 1) only the value for the '2.5' plate?

```
def plates_for(lb)
lb = (lb - 45) / 2
  plate_values = {'45': 45, '25': 25,'10': 10, '5': 5, '2.5': 2.5}
  pairs = plate_values.map do |plate, weight|
    number_of_plates = lb / weight
    lb = lb % weight
    [plate, number_of_plates]
  end

  plates_needed = pairs.select { |plate, weight| weight > 0 }
  p plates_needed.to_h
end

plates_for(140)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:**

```
plates_needed[:'2.5'] = plates_needed[:'2.5'].round
```

By default, this will round to the nearest integer, and **up** if it's halfway between. If you wish to use a different behaviour for rounding to the nearest half, you can specify an optional keyword:

```
2.5.round(half: :up)      #=> 3 (DEFAULT)
2.5.round(half: :down)    #=> 2
2.5.round(half: :even)    #=> 2
3.5.round(half: :up)      #=> 4 (DEFAULT)
3.5.round(half: :down)    #=> 3
3.5.round(half: :even)    #=> 4
```

Alternatively, if you want to _always_round down then use `Integer#floor`; and if you want to *always* round up then use `Integer#ceil`.

**Full Solution:**

```
def plates_for(lb)
  lb = (lb - 45).to_f / 2
  plate_values = [45, 25, 10, 5, 2.5]
  pairs = plate_values.map do |weight|
    number_of_plates = (lb / weight).round
    lb -= number_of_plates * weight
    [weight, number_of_plates]
  end.to_h

  pairs.select { |weight, number_of_plates| number_of_plates > 0 }
end

p plates_for(140) #=> {45=>1, 5=>1}
```

I have changed several subtle parts of your code. Note that the final result in my code is **different**! I get `{45=>1, 5=>1}`, which is correct. The changes are:

- Added `to_f` on line 2. Without this, you are rounding down the required weight on each side of the bar by `0.5` if the total required weight was even. For example, `(140 - 45) / 2 == 47`, but `(140 - 45).to_f / 2 == 47.5`.
- Define `plate_values` as a simple `Array`, to avoid confusion. There was no need to initialise this as a `Hash`.
- Add `Integer#round` to the number of plates calculation. This prevents non-integer values ever being assigned here. As discussed above, there are variations you could choose to use here.
- Since `(lb / weight).round` may **not** be the same as `lb % weight` (i.e. if we rounded up!), it would be wrong to use this value here. Always deduct the amount of weight that we've actually added to the bar.
- Call `.to_h` immediately on the result of this mapping, for simplification.
- No need to assign another variable below, for simplification.

Comment: I was trying this solution, but I get the following error: 
`no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: @KyKy that is becuase `plates_needed` is an `Array` due to the call to `map` that generates `pairs` you could add a `to_h` to the end of that mapping and this should work

Comment: @KyKy OK... I had a more thorough look through the code so that I could give a _complete_ code sample. I actually found several bugs, so changed it significantly. See my above edit, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

```
def plates_for(lb)
  lb = (lb - 45).fdiv(2)
  plate_values = { '45': 45, '25': 25, '10': 10, '5': 5, '2.5': 2.5 }
  pairs = {}
  plate_values.each do |plate, weight|
    pairs[plate], lb = lb.divmod(weight)
  end
  pairs[:'2.5'] += 1 if lb > 0
  pairs.select { |_, count| count > 0 }
end

plates_for(140) #=> {:"45"=>1, :"2.5"=>1}
```

Notable changes:

- I use [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv) to convert the remaining *lb* to a decimal number.
- Within the loop, I calculate *quotient* and *remainder* via [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) which ensures that the number of plates is an integer.
- After the loop, I'm adding another `2.5` plate if the remainder is not yet zero.